# Will skipping a quest prevent me from getting an achievement?

Tags: achievements, knightmare-tower

In *Knightmare Tower* for iOS, you have the ability to skip/bypass a quest by paying gold coins. If I skip a quest by paying for it, will that not allow me to get the Conqueror achievement, which is described as Complete all quests?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, it will not prevent you from unlocking the "Conqueror" achievement!

Comment: Hi Dom, and welcome to Arqade!  Could you expand of this?  Did you test this yourself or find a source online?